# Django pagination - nice urls

Tags: django, pagination

I did pagination in my django projet. Everything works just perfect, but my urls looks terrible, like

```
host:8000/?page=1
```

How to create nice urls like

```
host:8000/page/2/ or host:8000/2/
```

I use standard Paginator class via ListView

How to do this w/o third party code ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you define url pattern like this:

```
url(r'^/page/(?P<page>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.list_view'),
```

then `ListView` will pass `page` url keyword into paginator.

Notice:
Each path segment is supposed to be a valid resource, so it's not clear what you will display on `/path/` URL.

Django pagination system assumes that webpages will default to using the URL query, so it's recommended to keep it as a URL query and it's more revealing.